# Revert changes using Local history after push force?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I use Android Studio and I did by mistake a Git push force to my project. I want to undo the push force and revert back my local changes to my project, because my project is new and I did not commited any thing.

Can I revert all the latest changes which were before I did push force using Local history feature in Android Studio? 
Can I see all local changes which I did before  I clicked on push force using Local history feature.  I wonder if all local changes will be saved in Local history even if I did force push?

Note: Now I dont have the project becuase its not in my own computer. Therefore I just wonder and asking here to fix the problem later.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. look at `git reflog` to find the old commit you want to be at the head of, `git reset --hard` to it, and `git push --force` again;
2. Use `git log` to find the commits you don’t want, `git revert` them, and push normally; or
3. Find someone else with a clone that has the correct history and ask them to `git push --force`

The reflog shorthand `@@{n}` can be helpful here. N can be a number or even a date (see `git help reflog` and `git help revisions`).

Comment: But I did not  did any commit to my code so I dont have any commits, as i said above my project is new and I did not commited any thing. 
I wonder if all local changes will be saved in Local history even if I did force push?

Comment: You cant possibly have had anything to force-push if you didnt commit, *unless* you were *behind* the project’s history. That is, they committed, but you didn’t have those commits, so you actually took the project back in time. If that’s the case, option 3 is the only option (though they won’t need to force it). If no such person exists, I’m afraid you’ve lost whatever you overwrote.

Comment: Now I try to commit/push/ push force in a project in android studio in my own computer. In VSC => Local History => Show History    I can see all changes I did one month before until now even after push force. It will be great If I can see all local changes which I did before Push force in the project I wondered about. 
Did you know if all local changes will be saved in Local history even if I did git force push?